# How to set spring cloud config override the local configurations(which has been set as first priority)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config-server

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        LOGGER.debug("Starting spring boot application class");
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).initializers(new MproSpringContextInit()).run(args);
    }
```

I am setting MproSpringContextInit as first priorities.

```
public void initialize(AbstractApplicationContext applicationContext) {

        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();

        MutablePropertySources propertySources = environment.getPropertySources();

        ArchaiusPropertySource bridgeSource =
                new ArchaiusPropertySource(PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME, buildConfiguration());

        propertySources.addFirst(bridgeSource);
```

So the problem is after doing actuator/refresh too i am unable to get latest value from spring cloud config server as the property is available in MproSpringContextInit.so it's returning same value by not even looking in cloud config value. Any way we can get updated value from cloud config server?